# A generic error occurred in GDI+ exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, bitmap

I have few rows of VB.NET code:

```
   Dim dest As String = "C:\Users\Yonapms1\Desktop\Sample Pictures2"
   Dim img As Bitmap = New Bitmap("C:\Users\Yonapms1\Desktop\Sample Pictures\Tulips.jpg")

    img.Save(dest)
```

In  **img.Save(dest)**  row I get this exception:

Any idea why i get this exeption?

**A generic error occurred in GDI+.**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are trying to save an image as a folder

Comment: Cole,i want to save it as file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be trying to move the image from a folder called "Sample Pictures" to another folder called "Sample Pictures2". If so, you are better off doing the following:

```
File.Move("C:\Users\Yonapms1\Desktop\Sample Pictures\Tulips.jpg", "C:\Users\Yonapms1\Desktop\Sample Pictures2\Tulips.jpg")
```